# How to set parameter filters in ToolValidator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, parameters, tool-validation, value-list

I am populating `parameter[2]` using validation code provided by ESRI. How can I modify this code to repeat for `parameter[3]` what was done for `parameter[2]`? To elaborate...param[0] is a user supplied  feature class.  param[1] is fields from provided feature class. param[2] provides sorted values from selected field, and i would like to provide and sort these same values again in param[3]...

```py
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
     """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()
    self.fcfield = (None, None)

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parmater
    has been changed."""
    if self.params[0].value and self.params[1].value:
      fc, col = str(self.params[0].value), str(self.params[1].value)
      if self.fcfield != (fc, col):
        self.fcfield = (fc, col)
        self.params[2].filter.list = [str(val) for val in
                                    sorted(
                                      set(
                                        row.getValue(col)
                                        for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, None, None,
                                                                      col)
                                          )
                                       )
                                  ]
    if self.params[2].value not in self.params[2].filter.list:
      self.params[2].value = self.params[2].filter.list[0]

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
```

Comment: Can you verbally describe what is going on here? What does each parameter represent? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please see revised post...

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/89979/edit) to provide additional details rather than the comments.

Comment: I am still unclear on how parameter 3 is different from parameter 2.

Comment: It should not be different.  Only param[2] will provide 'origin' as string and param[3] intended to represent 'destination' as string from point feature class.  They will later be passed as string using sql expression to tool arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to take the results of the line

```
[str(val) for val in sorted(set(row.getValue(col) for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, None, None, col)))]
```

and assign it to both parameter 2 and parameter 3.

To do that, you could just assign the result of the above line to a variable, and then set the `filter.list` property of both parameters to that variable.

Thus your code would then look something like this:

```py
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
     """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()
    self.fcfield = (None, None)

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parmater
    has been changed."""
    if self.params[0].value and self.params[1].value:
      fc, col = str(self.params[0].value), str(self.params[1].value)
      if self.fcfield != (fc, col):
        self.fcfield = (fc, col)

        # Get the unique values of the field 'col' in the feature class 'fc'
        unique_values = [str(val) for val in
                            sorted(
                                set(
                                    row.getValue(col)
                                        for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, None, None, col)
                                )
                            )
                        ]

        # Assign the unique_values list to parameters 2 and 3
        self.params[2].filter.list = unique_values
        self.params[3].filter.list = unique_values

    # Set the default values of parameters 2 and 3 to the first item in the list
    if self.params[2].value not in self.params[2].filter.list:
      self.params[2].value = self.params[2].filter.list[0]
    if self.params[3].value not in self.params[3].filter.list:
      self.params[3].value = self.params[3].filter.list[0]

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
```

Comment: Thanks @blah238 this works exactly as I hoped! Where might I apply the additional validation to be sure the destination selection is not the same as origin selection?

Comment: Ask a separate question.